Is the group $\langle x,y \mid xy^n = yx^n \rangle $ trivial?
I’m currently browsing through Clara Löh’s book “Geometric Group Theory - an introduction”, and came across the exercise 2.E.14, which gives some examples of presentations of groups and asks to determine whether they are isomorphic to others. In particular it asks if the following group is trivial: \begin{equation} \langle x,y \mid xy^{2014} = yx^{2014} \rangle. \end{equation}
I have been tinkering with this example for a bit but cannot seem to find a suitable argument one way or the other. Any hint would be much appreciated!

Why would it be ? What can you say about $x^2$ ?

Abelianize it first.

@SteveD Of course, now I see it! Thank you!

Consider the map from this group to the cyclic group of order 2013 that takes $x$ to a generator and $y$ to $e$. The map induces a surjective homomorphism. Hence the group is not trivial.

No. Its abelianisation is
$$\langle x, y\mid x^{n-1}=y^{n-1}, xy=yx\rangle,$$
of which $\Bbb Z_{n-1}^2$ is a quotient.

Let me say more about this group (for $n\ge 1$): it is a semiproduct $\mathbf{Z}\ltimes F_n$ ($F_n$ free on $n$ generators).
Namely let $z_1,\dots,z_n$ be the free generators of $F_n$. Define inductively for $i\le 0$ $z_i=z_{i+1}\dots z_{i+n}$ and, for $i>n$, $z_i=(z_{i-n+1}\dots z_{i-1})^{-1}z_{i-n}$. So $z_i=z_{i+1}\dots z_{i+n}$ for all $i\in\mathbf{Z}$.
Define the endomorphism $f$ of $F_n$ mapping $z_i\mapsto z_{i+1}$ for $1\le i\le n$. Then it follows that $f(z_i)=z_{i+1}$ for all $i$; in particular this is an automorphism.
Let $G$ be the corresponding semidirect product (mapping torus): it thus has the presentation
$$G=\langle x,z_i:\;z_i=z_{i+1}\dots z_{i+n},\;xz_ix^{-1}=z_{i+1}\; (i\in\mathbf{Z}), \rangle.$$
All relations $z_i=z_{i+1}\dots z_{i+n}$ are conjugate to each other (by some power of $x$) so we can erase all but one, and get the presentation
$$G=\langle x,z_i:\;z_0=z_{1}\dots z_{n},\;z_i=x^iz_0x^{-1}\; (i\in\mathbf{Z}) \rangle,$$
where we see that all generators $z_i$ become redundant and we get the presentation (with $z_0=z$)
$$G=\langle x,z:\;z=xzx^{-1}.x^2zx^{-1}\dots x^nzx^{-n} \rangle.$$
Noting that $xzx^{-1}.x^2zx^{-1}\dots x^nzx^{-n}=(xz)^nx^{-n}$, and
writing $y=xz$, we get the presentation
$$G=\langle x,y:\;x^{-1}y=y^nx^{-n} \rangle,$$
which is exactly the original presentation.
(To find this in a deductive way: go backwards. Since $z=x^{-1}y$ is in the kernel of the unique [up to sign] homomorphism $u$ to $\mathbf{Z}$ it is natural to make the change of variable and thus try to describe the kernel of $u$.)
